# How to bind params with mysqli query

Tags: php, mysqli, bindparam

I am struggling for over an hour now with something that should be fairly simple.
I want to get rows from my mysqli database and when I run my query from phpmyadmin I get expected results but when I run it (`with bind_param`) from my php code I get 0 results:

```
$sql = $connection->prepare('SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)) 
                             FROM table1 
                             WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time) >= ? 
                               AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)) <= ? 
                               AND column3 = ?') 
                            or trigger_error($connection->error, E_USER_ERROR);
$sql->bind_param('sss', $value1, $value2, $value3);
$sql->execute() or trigger_error($sql->error, E_USER_ERROR);

if ($sql->num_rows == 0){
    echo "yay";
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: none, I tried to get any error messages but there weren't any

Comment: @Lenny I've added an answer that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the result set for MySQLi prepared statements. Adjust your code as follows:

```
// Execute query
$sql->execute();

// Store result
$sql->store_result();

echo $sql->num_rows;
```

PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Comment: `store_result()` it was. And I was pulling my hair already. Thanks